# Bean ID for the list of items produced by Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring, arraylist, spring-batch, applicationcontext

In Spring Batch, after a ItemReader or ItemProcessor returns it's item object, the framework puts that item into an ArrayList to be passed to the ItemWriter.

I need to gain access to that ArrayList of items in an ItemProcessor. The core functionality I need is to access the Arraylist while the ItemReader/ItemProcessor is processing it's chunk.

My thought was to use an ApplicationContextAware ItemProcessor, allowing me to make the call below:

```
ArrayList<? extends Item> items = context.getBean("items", ArrayList.class)
```

But the bean is not named items.

Do you know how I can gain access to that ArrayList, or the name of the Bean so I can force it in there?

Comment: What is the purpose of this requirement?  What are you attempting to do with the list of items?

Answer (score 2):

Use the following spring batch annotation (available since spring batch 2.0)

> @BeforeWrite 
> Marks a method to be called before an item is passed to
>   an ItemWriter
> Expected signature: void beforeWrite(List
>   items)

Method on your writer marked with this annotation will be execute for every chunk before
your write method.

Comment: Will this work in an ItemProcessor? The requirement is to access the ArrayList of items in the ItemProcessor.

Comment: It’s the same array list.
But if you prefer using this at the  ItemProcessor level use 
@BeforeProcess/@AfterProcess 
But this will give an access to one item only

Comment: That's it, I need to get the ArrayList in the ItemProcessor.

Comment: I would like to clarify this point again. The ItemProcessor process stuff at a single item level, so @BeforeProcess/@AfterProcess will give an access to one item only. Spring batch execute per chunk the following flow (regarding the annotations maintained above) Reader[ArrayList]-> BeforeProcess[item]-> ItemProcessor[item]-> AfterProcess[item]-> beforeWrite[ArrayList]-> ItemWriter[ArrayList]. Let me know if this clarify the point and I will update my answer. –